# How to update D3 chart when data is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am using D3 charts to display the data on screen. Data is updated from WebApi. Once data is updated I want to refresh data in chart.

here is the code

```
 $scope.config = {
        title: 'Products',
        tooltips: true,
        labels: false,
        mouseover: function () { },
        mouseout: function () { },
        click: function () { },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            //could be 'left, right'
            position: 'right'
        }
    };


$http.put(WebApiURL.GetWebApiURL() + 'api/ReportPerformance', data)
     .then(function (response) {
         $scope.PerformanceData = response.data;
         $scope.LoadingData = "";
         $scope.chartdata = [];
         var tempchartdata = [];
         angular.forEach($scope.PerformanceData, function (value) {
             tempchartdata.push(value.ReportTimeInSeconds);
         });
         $scope.chartdata = tempchartdata;
     }), function errorCallback(x, y, z) {
         $scope.LoadingData = "Error while generating report:= " + x.ExceptionMessage;
     };
    }
```

this web call updating data `$scope.chartdata`.

Chart definition in html...

```
<div data-ac-chart="'bar'"
     data-ac-data="chartdata"
     data-ac-config="chartConfig"
     style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"
     class="chart">
</div>
```

But when data come from webApi, it is updating `$scope.chartdata` but it is not reflecting on screen.

Added plunker... http://plnkr.co/edit/a0mVRL0Jo9ah8Om8ONTc

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: You need to put the code that draws/updates the chart in the `$http.put` callback or else add a `$scope.$watch` and put it there. Can you show the code that actually makes the chart?

Comment: THis is the actual code that draw the chart. Can you point me to some example for your suggestions.

Comment: *"This is the actual code that draw the chart"*... what are you saying? There is not a single line of D3 in that code.

Comment: Can you see the div tag in my question... that actually drawing the chart on the screen.

Comment: I just give up...

Answer (score 0):

you should watch the `$scope.dataAcData` in your directive and update the D3 in

```
scope.$watch('dataAcData',function(){
  //update your d3 here
})
```

Comment: I have not created any directive for chart. I am just directly using whatever provided by D3 as Mentioned in my question

Comment: it should be have a directive, or where do you bind your $scope.chartdata to? and where is your d3 code?

Comment: are you sure you are not using `angular-charts`? for I think these `data-ac-data`,`data-ac-config` is used in `angular-charts` directive .And about your plunker,I didn't see any code about d3,and it doesn't draw any thing on your web,you must miss something

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply method, I thing its now updated because, $digest not working in your code. Wrap your code around

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
            //your code
        });




 $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.dataAcData
        });

go through http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html link, Hope it will help you
```

Comment: for more detail visit on